# How to add crashlytics in cordova app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crashlytics

I m working on a ionic framework application in that i have ios and android platform i need to add crashlytics in my app.i add the app in crashlytics using Xcode and for android i added the following plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/smistry-toushay/cordova-crashlytics-plugin.git --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_SECRET=YOUR CRASHLYTICS API SECRET HERE --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY=YOUR CRASHLYTICS API KEY HERE
```

My problem is when i get the log from crashlytics it shows the number of user etc in under ios app only.

Comment: Did you found any solution to this ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this tutorial. It was really helpful to me and very simple to follow. http://blog.ms07.at/2016/01/19/fabric-io-and-ionic/. It shows how to add to android and then I used the https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin plugin to get it working.

Once you add fabric to android studio and get the app set up, my advise that is not on the tutorial is to run your app via command line using ionic run android. Then fabric would recognize your app and you can install the plugin. Works great!!